# Pass main's *argv[] to a function that is being called by another function?

Tags: c, pointers, scope, argv, args

So I have my main function, and 2 other functions, func1 and func2.
main is gettings the arguments from the user, passes them to func1.
fun1 checks something, and then wants to send the arguments to func2.

How can I do it?

```
 int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
  if( argc == 3 ){
    func1(argv);
  }

void func1(char **argv){
if(strcmp(argv[2], "-win"))
    func2(argv);
}

void func2(char ***argv){ //is this the right way?
......
}
```

I mean I know that func1 is receiving the arguments because when I tried it without sending them to func2, it worked.
But I'm trying to figure out how to send them to func2 from func1.

Comment: What do you think `argc` is for; don't you need it? Also why do you vary the type of `argv` in `func2`?

Comment: But if we will remove func2 from my code, we will see that func1 works fine without the need to send argc.

Comment: You can pass `argv` to `func2` the same way you passed it to `func1`.  That is, use this signature: `void func2(char **argv)`.

Comment: It does not work. I'm trying to pass argv from func1 to func2, not from main to func2.

Comment: You can (and probably should) use `void func2(char **argv)` and call it with `func2(argv)`; or alternatively, you can use `void func2(char ***argv)` and call it with `func2(&argv)`.  However, the alternative is unlikely to be sensible.  You'd have to be modifying where the local variable `argv` in `func1()` is pointing at for there to be any purpose in the extra level of indirection — and there's no evidence of such a change being recognized in `func1()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code in file `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void func1(char **argv);
void func2(char **argv);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // you are need to pass 2 things to run this
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        func1(argv);
    }
    return 0;
}

void func1(char **argv)
{
    if (strcmp(argv[2], "-win")==0)
        func2(argv);
}

void func2(char **argv)
{
    printf("%s\n", argv[2]);
}
```

Running `gcc -Wall  main.c -o main  && ./main  f -win` you get the
output: `-win` to the console. You shouldn't manipulate data within `argv` and it is a safer bet to just change `func2` to:

```
char *func2(char **argv)
{
    // Return some value after receiving argv
}
```

and return whatever type your result is of the manipulation you are wanting to do.